# How do I break down my components and files in C

Tags: design, c, file-structure

I've been designing an event processor for state machines in C and I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to break down my components in simpler and smaller `*.h` and `*.c` files.

Specifically I'm not sure whether it's best to separate declarations and user types from a component in order to use them in multiple other components.
I'm giving an example...

Let's say we have `LibA.h`

```
typedef int MyTypeA;

typedef struct
{
 ...
}MySctructA;

void LibA_foo(MyTypeA x);
void LibA_bar(MySctructA *y);
```

Now if I want to use either the `MyTypeA` or `MyStructA` in other components I'll have to include `LibA.h` but that would expose everything the file contains. So, I'm wondering if it's a good practice to create another `*.h` file and keep my declarations and user types there and then include that header file into each component.

I'd usually do it in either way but I wanna strengthen my software engineering skills that needed for maintainability, reusability and testability.

Comment: Why would there be a use case for component B using `MyTypeA` or `MyStructA` without needing/wanting to use any of the `LibA*` functions?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Good question! That's my problem I think. I broke a component into smaller pieces and I think that I shouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

One popular scheme is:

- One component per file.
- Each component has a header file 'component-name.h', implementation 'component-name.c[pp,xx]' and unit test 'component.t.c[pp,xx]'
- Components that use other components include the header files they need.

At first, this seems like a lot of includes and boiler plate code, but very quickly becomes an easy pattern to follow and the confidence that every component is tested helps to pin down problems quickly.

If you have public API versus private API, you can introduce a folder structure for the private pieces, but the headers might need to expose some minimum amount of the private implementation for it to work. This is where the [Pimpl pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) comes in.

There are [whole books](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Large-Scale-Architecture-Component-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201717069) about this stuff because it matters at scale when you've got multiple teams of multiple people sharing a code base.

Answer (score 0):

It really does depend on whether a type declaration has broader uses than just your LibA. If `MyStructA` is an encapsulation of a concept, such as a node in a list, that could easily be incorporated into algorithms or solutions that are otherwise unrelated to whatever `LibA` is used for, then the answer to your question is a firm ***perhaps***.

The fact that it may actually be useful elsewhere, does not oblige you to publish it separately.

- Are there existing well-known and well written libraries in circulation that cover the same ground?

  - Should you adopt one of those instead of rolling your own?
- Are you willing to bear the burden of testing and maintaining that separate unit for a wider audience than just the consumers of your LibA?
- Are there common actions (insert, remove, iterate, etc.) on the type(s) that can also be shared along with them?
- Do you have any other libraries that could benefit from that unit of code?

As a general rule, most of the types you create for a particular purpose, won't actually be very useful without the functions that encapsulate the algorithms for which the type was created. A separate header file carries cultural/organizational, design, development, maintenance and compile time costs. If you are working alone, the cultural/organizational aspects may seem negligible, and you can often ignore them, but you are taking on an unquantifiable debt to a future, where your shared code might actually be taken up and used by others.

As you develop your tool-box of reusable code, you should always keep your eye out for violations of the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule. If you find yourself creating identical or very similar types in more than one library, you should consider whether the extra effort of refactoring those libraries to share some common type definitions and/or algorithms is warranted (it often is).

There's some common rules in programming:

> Never optimize early.

> Make it work correctly first, then measure, then decide.

Those apply at all levels of development and life in general. Sharing common types is a form of optimization and all optimizations have trade-offs. You may have to modify the types to make them useful, or consumer pressure may force changes on those types or additional code burden along side of them. The DRY principle is a very good rule to follow, but until you are actually about to repeat yourself, it is unlikely that it applies to your LibA example.

It's good to think global, but never lose focus on the local reality.